# Should "Review Low Quality Posts" present the option to "Move the post as comment"

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I was presented with the following low quality answer:

> see this link click here
>
> see last_row() and previous_row()....

which is very short and looks as a good fit for a comment, but there is no such option. Only **Looks Good, Edit, Recommend Deletion, Skip.**

The post itself is helpful and I will not recommend deletion, but it fits better as a comment.

Do you think that such an option is a good idea?
Or to prompt the one who posted it to move it himself?

I started the discussion in order to find out why it is ambiguous if it is and how to improve the labels of the buttons if possible.

Comment: But the comment should appear as posted by whom? You or the OP? If it is posted as you, are you okay with taking the burden of verifying the correctness? Also it counts as plagiarism(but of course attribution can be added). And posting on some one else's behalf should not even be in question.

Comment: It is only about moving the post without any change to the content. Which implies that the responsibility for the correctness of the content remains on the poster.

Comment: yes but your name would appear next to the comment. So you will have to make sure if the content is actually relevant/correct.

Comment: actually Mods have the power to convert added answer into a comment by OP. I dont see it occuring frequently.

Comment: Its ok. If you have that much repo you are granted the authority - which means you are trusted that you behave responsibly.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I thought that marking the answer as not an answer would send it to the LQP queue. The author asks about posts already found in the LQP queue.

Comment: I've done some more digging: Recommend deletion -> This is commentary on another post, not an answer marks it to be converted to a comment, and doesn't actually delete the question (note that even posts from people who don't have the post comment privilege can be converted). Just do that.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth there is no option "the answer as not an answer". 
Why my question was downvoted? Simple SO hate or it has no merit? I am asking this question because I did not know what should I do about this real situation. I do screen the queues because I want to participate and improve.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth "Recommend Deletion" does not imply "Mark it so that another user may move it". The intent of the button is not clear.

Comment: Downvotes on meta show dislike or disagreement, possibly people who already know what I've figured out. You only get _not an answer_ if you go to the post itself, in review you should _recommend deletion -> This is commentary on another post, not an answer_. You're not discussing the name of that item. You might, but that's not your current question.

Comment: Dislike or disagreement? It is hard for me to believe that I have incurred dislike for a meaningful question as this one. Disagreement? With a question? This is basic stuff here and I won`t name it. Just regret that I have tried to participate in a normal conversation but incurred that kind of a conversation. And a -5 downvote.

Comment: You shouldn’t take votes personally. In meta votes don’t matter. And your question can be interpreted as a proposal (I assumed as much). So some can simply downvote disagreeing with the perceived proposal. No need to get all flustered about it.

Answer (score 6):

My take on this:

You write about "posts", but I think you actually mean "answers" (since converting a question to a comment doesn't make a lot of sense).

Many of the answers that appear on the LQP queue are from users who do not have the commenting privilege yet, and of those a fair number are doing so attempting to circumvent that block; so they are breaking the rules on purpose.

Converting these to comments would incentivize the "*posting comments as answers*" behavior for those users, not something I think we'd want.

If the answer author **do** have posting privileges, **they should know better already**. By posting low quality posts they pass the quality review burden up the chain. If those posts are bad enough as to merit a "recommend deletion"; they should probably be rightfully deleted, both to get rid of LQ stuff and to help the poster learn that they should post better quality answers.

Finally, nothing stops you from commenting yourself using the information from the post you are recommending to delete, if you really believe the information would be useful, but doesn't work as a an answer.

Comment: The queue is named Posts. I suggest that there are both - questions and answers too. Otherwise it should be named Answers only.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov The queue is named Posts. And there are both. But you can't convert questions to comments, can you? _Where_ would you post that comment?

Comment: No, I can not. But it looked like the proper solution for such a situation.

Comment: @Ognyan Converting a question to a comment? That doesn't make any sense. Again: how would you go about converting a question to a comment?

Comment: Tthe app knows if the post is a question or an answer and can present the proper options accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, sure. But again: your proposal only makes any sense if directed at answers. Because questions cannot be converted to comments in any sensible way.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov The queue is named low quality posts because it used to be about both questions and answers, but it has since been changed (and has been like this for quite a long time now) to only deal with answers.  You won't ever find questions in that queue these days.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it might be a good idea upon first reflection (and, indeed, I thought this would be a good idea myself many years ago), but experience tells me it would not be a good idea. Such a feature would encourage reviewers to convert what they consider to be low-quality answers into comments.

There is a widespread misbelief that if you are going to post a crappy answer, you should do it as a comment. That is, of course, not true. You have two choices when you want to post a crappy answer: (1) don't, or (2) post it and take your downvotes in stride. As a reviewer, the corresponding choices are (1) delete, or (2) downvote.

Note that "make it a comment" is not one of the choices. Comments are for posts that request clarification or add additional information (as indicated in the placeholder text in the comment box). They are not for crappy answers. Nor are they for "short" answers, which is another type of answer that reviewers commonly (but wrongly) believe "should have been posted as a comment". An answer is either attempting to provide an answer to the question, or it isn't.

So, it is very much intentional that reviewers aren't given the option to convert an answer into a comment, because most of the time, that power would be misused.

If you think the answer is either not an answer, or total garbage, then you should recommend it be deleted. Otherwise, you can downvote it and/or edit it.

Beyond that, like [yivi said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358819), in cases where you were *correctly* converting an answer to a comment, the whole reason it was posted as an answer was because the poster lacked sufficient privileges to post a comment in the first place. In other words, they were subverting our rules and intentionally doing it wrong. Reviewers should not be enabling this behavior.

Moderators do have the ability to convert answers into comments, but we use it only on rare occasion when the answer actually is attempting to ask for clarification or add additional information, and using our discretion regarding the above-mentioned concern about users attempting to subvert site rules. Anecdotally, most of the time I find myself converting an answer to a comment is when it's an *old* answer someone has flagged, dating from the time before comments even existed as a feature on this site.

Since moderators do have this ability, if you happen upon an answer that you *strongly* believe should be converted to a comment, then you can flag it for moderator attention, making your case convincingly. If we agree, we'll do the conversion. In the mean time, you should still handle the post as you otherwise would: recommend deletion, edit, and/or downvote.